# Same wordpress directory and parameter conflict

Tags: wordpress

root_directory:

- wp-content/
- wp-admin/
- wp-includes/
- stackoverflow

The text above is the sample directories in my root folder.
This time I want to create a page named "stackoverflow".
Everything is working, the page is created and the url is

www.mywebsite.com/stackoverflow

Now, every time I visit www.mywebsite.com/stackoverflow, it only loads the directory and not the page.

Any solutions for this guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your directory name or your file name.
You cant keep directory and file with same name in same directory.

Comment: any solutions sir? what about htaccess? because I really need to create a directory the same with the page name I've created for specific purpose.

Comment: if you write htaccess code with .php extensions ( www.mywebsite.com/stackoverflow.php ).

may be it works.

Comment: Hey guys. I have one more question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472687/how-to-read-php-file-anywhere-in-the-url-when-i-call